# Flutter - firebase_auth_web 5.4.0 depends on intl ^0.17.0 but I must use higher version (intl ^0.18.0)

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, intl, pubspec

Flutter Dependencies error:

```
Because firebase_auth_web 5.4.0 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and no versions of firebase_auth_web match >5.4.0 <6.0.0, firebase_auth_web ^5.4.0 requires intl ^0.17.0.
So, because ventus depends on both intl ^0.18.0 and firebase_auth_web ^5.4.0, version solving failed.
exit code 1
```

I have other dependencies and I must use `intl: ^0.18.0`

Is there a way to resolve the dependency with `firebase_auth_web` ?

It originates from  `firebase_auth: ^4.5.0` - this is the latest version

I tried lowering dependencies - but no success - I eventually get to non-null-safty packages and can't continue from there.

Comment: I was in same issue. I solved this issue by adding dependency_overrides: 
please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add dependency_overrides after dependecies

```
dependencies:
  # for localizations (firebase_ui_auth uses)
  flutter_localizations:
      sdk: flutter

# for rest
dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.18.0
```